# Hydroboration oxidation reaction on trans,trans,trans-1,5,9-cyclododecatriene

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, hydrocarbons

> [image]

**The given solution:**

[image]

Could some one please explain the mechanism of the reaction? How it proceeds and why it proceeds that particular way? Also, what is the use of $\ce{CO}$?

Comment: The CO is the source of the central carbon

Comment: Well, I hope you're asking about Q. Because, while P does look kinda weird, it's actually very easy to understand if you [know the mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroboration%E2%80%93oxidation_reaction).

Comment: @Alphanerd not a complete answer, but this should put you on the right track: http://www-oc.chemie.uni-regensburg.de/OCP/ch/chb/oc5/B_Organometallics.pdf

Comment: There are two questions here. The first is, basically, what is the mechanism for hydroboration oxidation of an alkene. That is covered in various textbooks and online resources. The second is carbonylation of organoboranes, which is significantly more complicated because there's triple migration (and it turns out the migration is condition dependent) and is definitely not covered in most introductory organic textbooks. The original reports on hydroboration by H.C. Brown cover this topic quite extensively, so if you're really interested, you should look those up.